# Package in R: error messages and zero subjects

Tags: r, package, irr

My data frame (Test1) is correctly formatted n*m (n= 300 subjects, m= 15 raters):

```
 x rater1 rater2 rater3 ...... rater15
y
Case1 1 1 NA
Case2 1 NA NA
Case3 2 1 2
.
.
.
Case300
```

Fleiss & Error message --

```
`kappam.fleiss(Test1)'
Error in ratings[i, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

Agree & Error message --

```
agree(Test1, tolerance=0)
Percentage agreement (Tolerance=0)
 Subjects = 0 
   Raters = 15 
  %-agree = NaN
```

I looked at the example data(diagnoses)

```
> kappam.fleiss(diagnoses)
 Fleiss' Kappa for m Raters

 Subjects = 30 
   Raters = 6 
    Kappa = 0.43 

        z = 17.7 
  p-value = 0 
> agree(diagnoses, tolerance=0)
 Percentage agreement (Tolerance=0)

 Subjects = 30 
   Raters = 6 
  %-agree = 16.7 
>
```

Can someone please help me - why my subjects = 0? I believe this is the reason why my kappam.fleiss isn't working. My row.names are labeled.

Comment: I solved it -> make sure that the data-frame/matrix does not have NA as string or data-type. Just leave the cells empty.

Answer (score 0):

Fleiss's Kappa at its core will fail if there are raters who have not rated all of the items. I suggest you use Krippendorff's Alpha instead. It is part of the same "irr" package that you are using already.